# Ubuntu 16.04 and Samba access TO an OS X 10.11.6 machine

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing

OK... I know this may not be the best place to ask this. 
However, the decline of AppleCorp continues. The online community is now basically  useless for anything beyond the most basic templated answers... And, as far as "genius" goes... I'm pretty sure that word doesn't mean what they think it does... OK, enough of that.

I am trying to get my ubuntu 16.04 systems to access OS X 10.11.6 and MacOS 10.12.1 shares using Samba, which I have finally managed to get functioning nicely on all linux machines. None of the macs want to play ball with anyone not wearing their logo...

I can "see" the Mac's server in Network, I can click on it... And, the authorization window does pop up. I enter the correct credentials... and... after a few seconds, the authorization window reappears.

The Macs are in my hosts file. And, smb.conf uses hosts resolution AFTER WINS. The WINS server is Ubuntu. And, is doing a FINE job with the Linux boxes in the house.

In MacOS, I have shared my home folder. And, have enabled file sharing with the SMB option on. Ubuntu sees the workgroup and all servers configured within it. I just can't get past AUTH....

Ironically, MacOS can connect to the window where it shows the available shares on the Ubuntu machines... while clicking on one of them "should" trigger authorization. 
Instead, it closes the window and presents an error: "The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “homes” can’t be found." (SMH)

Anyone else encountered and possibly even, found a solution for this problem? more importantly, care to "share"? :-D

Thanks for reading.

Comment: This tip on the Apple forum solved my Samba problems with my 10.11.6 machine: https://discussions.apple.com/message/30260816#30260816 - hope it works for you too.

Comment: Could you please at least outline the solution. Links on the internet might become invalid over time which would render your answer useless.

Comment: @Pete : Thanks for the link. I had seen that one before. But, unfortunately I couldn't get things to work out on my system. I had since updated to 10.12. And, found that the situation with Samba AND NFS on 10.12. is even worse. So, I just dumped MacOS altogether and loaded Ubuntu on the system. It works now... <LOL>